# Access 2016 VBA command button to sort not working

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I need help alphabetically sorting a continuous list of records on a form.  Clicking button SortAZ is supposed to trigger this action.

Details:
tblPatients has a list of patient names and their ID numbers.  When I create a form based solely on this information, a cmd button is created and works as expected.  I want to also allow the user to filter the list by any criteria (say they only remember the first name, but not the ID or last name).

frmPatients has a header above the Detail section.  I can't seem to get vba to recognize the fields in the detail section.  I have tried several different combinations (see commented lines) and even renaming the Detail section.

```
 Private Sub SortAZClick()
      Me.FilterOn = False
      Me.OrderByOn = False
     'Me.LastName.SetFocus

     'Me.OrderBy = "LastName"
     'Me.OrderByOn = True
     'Me.Detail.OrderBy = "[LastName]"
     'Me.Detail!OrderBy = "LastName"
      Me.FilterResults!OrderBy = "[LastName]"

     'Me.Form.OrderBy = "LastName"
      Me.Form.OrderByOn = True
     'me.Detail!requery
      Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: _comment moved to an answer_

Answer (score 0):

Oh the horror!!!  The problem was in the first line.  Should have been `Private Sub SortAZ_Click()`  Simply leaving out the underscore prevented it from doing ANYTHING.